# constructors in java have me sad

Tags: java, constructor

The question is:

1. Write the definition of a class `Clock`.
2. The class has three instance variables : one of type int called hours , another of type boolean  called isTicking, and the last one of type  Integer  called  diff.
3. You should also write a constructor  that takes three parameters -- an int, a boolean  ,and another int.
4. The constructor should set the instance variables to the values  provided.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class Clock {
    private int hours; 

    private boolean isTicking;

    private Integer diff;

    public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, Integer diff;) {
        this.hours = hours; this.isTicking = isTicking; this.diff = diff;
    }

}
```

Comment: what makes you sad? the ctor not being parameterless?

Comment: Remove the semicolon after 'diff' inside your ctor

Comment: Semicolon in the Constructor is generating the error

Comment: Reading this made me sad :(

Comment: guys, turings craft is still throwing errors. ;-(

Comment: fixed it guys - apparently, i was suppose to use "int" instead of "Integer". but why though?

Comment: 'cause the question says the compiler should take "another int" not and integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine, except for the spurious semicolon:

```
public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, Integer diff;
                                                          ^ THIS
```

Remove it, and you'll be good to go.

> fixed it guys - apparently, i was suppose to use "int" instead of "Integer". but why though?

As far as I can see, by using `Integer` you've followed the instructions to the letter. Ask your instructor.

Comment: i have removed it. Yet, Turings Craft is throwing errors. :-(

Comment: @user2168239: Your code is fine. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, Integer diff;)
```

Should be

```
public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, Integer diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Colon after the Integer diff must be removed then it will run fine. It should be

```
public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, int diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  Clock ( int hours, boolean isTicking, Integer diff;)
```

You dont need a semicolon aftr `Integer diff`

Comment: @user2168239

What was the error thrown initially?

I dont think using **Integer** class instead of **int** datatype should be a problem. The wrappers would do the job implicitly.

(I know your errors are solved just want to know).

Comment: sorry this is coming late @Suvp.
In the question, they ask that the parameter be of type int. it is the instance that is an Integer type.